# Python Tkinter: Attach scrollbar to listbox as opposed to window

Tags: python, linux, listbox, tkinter, scrollbar

Here is a screenshot of my window at present:

[image: screenshot]

My problem is that I simply cannot get the scrollbar to appear attached to the right side of the listbox instead of the right side of the main window. The code is here:

```
from Tkinter import *

def onselect(event):
    w = event.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    info = find_info(value)
    listSelection.delete(0, END)
    listSelection.insert(END, "Node ID: " + info[0])
    listSelection.insert(END, "Owner/Description: " + info[1])
    listSelection.insert(END, "Last Latitude: " + info[2])
    listSelection.insert(END, "Last Longitude: " + info[3])



mapNodes = "http://ukhas.net/api/mapNodes"
nodeData = "http://ukhas.net/api/nodeData"
current_id = 0

window = Tk() # create window
window.configure(bg='lightgrey')
window.title("UKHASnet Node Manager")
window.geometry("680x400")

lbl1 = Label(window, text="Node List:", fg='black', font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold"))
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Node Information:", fg='black', font=("Helvetica", 16,"bold"))
lbl1.place(x=0, y=0)
lbl2.place(x=200, y=0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical")
listNodes = Listbox(window, width=20, height=20, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=("Helvetica", 12))
scrollbar.config(command=listNodes.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

listSelection = Listbox(window, width=50, height=4, font=("Helvetica", 12))

# pack objects onto window
listNodes.place(x=1, y=40)
listSelection.place(x=200, y=40)
```

Any help appreciated, and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.5

Matt

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You attached scrollbar to `window`

```
Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical")
```

Try to attache to `listNodes`

```
Scrollbar(listNodes, orient="vertical")
```

or create `Frame` with `Listbox` and attache scrollbar to that frame.

---

**EDIT:** example with `Frame`

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("680x500")

Label(window, text="Top label").pack()

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

listNodes = Listbox(frame, width=20, height=20, font=("Helvetica", 12))
listNodes.pack(side="left", fill="y")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
scrollbar.config(command=listNodes.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

listNodes.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for x in range(100):
    listNodes.insert(END, str(x))

Label(window, text="Bottom label").pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** frame in your code - I use `grid/pack` because I prefered it.

I add some code so now lists resize when window resizes.

```
from Tkinter import *

def onselect(event):
    w = event.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    info = find_info(value)
    listSelection.delete(0, END)
    listSelection.insert(END, "Node ID: " + info[0])
    listSelection.insert(END, "Owner/Description: " + info[1])
    listSelection.insert(END, "Last Latitude: " + info[2])
    listSelection.insert(END, "Last Longitude: " + info[3])



mapNodes = "http://ukhas.net/api/mapNodes"
nodeData = "http://ukhas.net/api/nodeData"
current_id = 0

window = Tk() # create window
window.configure(bg='lightgrey')
window.title("UKHASnet Node Manager")
window.geometry("680x400")

lbl1 = Label(window, text="Node List:", fg='black', font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold"))
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Node Information:", fg='black', font=("Helvetica", 16,"bold"))
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
lbl2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

frm = Frame(window)
frm.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S)
window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frm, orient="vertical")
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listNodes = Listbox(frm, width=20, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=("Helvetica", 12))
listNodes.pack(expand=True, fill=Y)

scrollbar.config(command=listNodes.yview)

listSelection = Listbox(window, height=4, font=("Helvetica", 12))
listSelection.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E+W+N)


for x in range(100):
    listNodes.insert(END, x)

for x in "ABCD":
listSelection.insert(END, x + ": ?")
```

[image]

Comment: Just one question furas, if I wanted to keep the original layout, ie, have the new frame you've defined in the original location of the listbox, is there a simple way to do thi?

Comment: Note that if you use the listbox as the parent of the scrollbar, the scrollbar will be on top of any text that appears at the right margin. If your listbox is wide enough to always have whitespace it won't be an issue, but if you have text that fills the line, the last character or two will be under the scrollbar. If you use the extra frame you won't have this problem.

Comment: @user3046180 see new example - your code with frame and with grid/pack.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `place` (which I *don't* recommend), just do some math to calculate the position of the scrollbar.

The better choice in this specific case is to use `grid`, because you clearly want things organized in rows and columns. The header is row 0, and the listbox/scrollbar combination(s) are in row 1. The first header goes in columns 0 and 1, the listbox in column 0, and the scrollbar in column 1. The second header goes in column 2, and the other listbox goes in column 3.