# How can I make the Tkinter scrollbar edit live

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to create a scrollbar that keeps adding another line of text every second. I want it to work "live" and keep adding another line of text.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

master = Tk()
while True:
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    listbox.insert(END, "Another line\n")
    listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

    scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This code creates an entirely new scrollbar and an entirely new listbox every second.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter: Attach scrollbar to listbox as opposed to window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656138/python-tkinter-attach-scrollbar-to-listbox-as-opposed-to-window)

Comment: create scrollbar and list only once before `while` loop. You could also use `root.after` instead of `while` and `sleep` to run some code periodically - it will not block `root.mainloop()` which has to work all time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `while True` and `sleep` in any GUI framework (in any language) because it can block `mainloop` and it can't get events froms system, send them to widgets and redraw window - so window freeze.

Every framework has some method to run code periodically (ie. `timer`).

`tkinter` has `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` for this

```
#from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter as tk
import time

# --- function ---

def add_line():
    listbox.insert('end', time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    root.after(1000, add_line)  # run `add_line` again after 1000ms (1s)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

listbox = tk.Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.pack(side='left', fill='both')

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

add_line()  # run `add_line` first time

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, how would I be able to add a line after asking for an input? For example python asks you for an input and if your input is something like "yes" it adds another line? Also can I make links within the scrollbar clickable? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you want to use GUI then learn how to use `Entry` + `Button` instead of `input()`. In `Entry` you can put text and `Button` can run function which will copy text from `Entry` to  `Listbox`. Or simple  create `Button` with text `Yes`.

Comment: do you means links in text in listbox, not in scrollbar? I'm not sure if you can do it in Listbox but you could try to do it with `tags` in `Text` but if you have link in longer text then you will have to on your own recognize link in this text - and it can be problem.

Comment: effbot.org: [Tkinter Text Widget Hyperlink Manager](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-hyperlink.htm)